# Create azure automation account using REST api from java

Tags: java, api, rest, azure, azure-automation

I am trying to create an automation account in Azure using REST API from java. Right now I am able to list images, create service using REST API from java but when I am trying to create an automation account I get the error:

```
   Forbidden
   <Error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" 
   xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <Code>ForbiddenError</Code>
   <Message>The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription.</Message>
   </Error>
```

JAVA class:

```
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.net.*;
  import java.security.*;
  import java.io.*;
  import java.security.KeyManagementException;
  import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
  import java.security.KeyStoreException;
  import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
  import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
  import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
  import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
  import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
  import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

  public class AzureRest
  {
        private static KeyStore getKeyStore(String keyStoreName, String password)
throws IOException
{
    KeyStore ks = null;
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        char[] passwordArray = password.toCharArray();
        fis = new java.io.FileInputStream(keyStoreName);
        ks.load(fis, passwordArray);
        fis.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (fis != null) {
            fis.close();
        }
    }
    return ks;
}

    private static SSLSocketFactory getSSLSocketFactory(String keyStoreName, String password)
throws UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyStoreException, 
NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, IOException {

    KeyStore ks = getKeyStore(keyStoreName, password);
    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
    keyManagerFactory.init(ks, password.toCharArray());

    SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    context.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, new SecureRandom());

    return context.getSocketFactory();
}

private static String getStringFromInputStream(InputStream is) {

    BufferedReader br = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}

private static String processGetRequest(URL url, String keyStore, String keyStorePassword) throws UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
    SSLSocketFactory sslFactory = getSSLSocketFactory(keyStore, keyStorePassword);
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setSSLSocketFactory(sslFactory);
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.addRequestProperty("x-ms-version", "2013-08-01");
    InputStream responseStream = (InputStream) con.getContent();
    String response = getStringFromInputStream(responseStream);
    responseStream.close();
    return response;
}

private static int processPostRequest(URL url, byte[] data, String contentType, String keyStore, String keyStorePassword) throws UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
    SSLSocketFactory sslFactory = getSSLSocketFactory(keyStore, keyStorePassword);
    HttpsURLConnection con = null;
    con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setSSLSocketFactory(sslFactory);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.addRequestProperty("x-ms-version", "2013-08-01");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(data.length));
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", contentType);

    DataOutputStream requestStream = new DataOutputStream (con.getOutputStream());
    requestStream.write(data);
    requestStream.flush();
    requestStream.close();

    System.out.println(con.getResponseMessage());

    InputStream error = ((HttpURLConnection) con).getErrorStream(); 

    BufferedReader br = null;
    if (error == null) {
         InputStream inputstream = con.getInputStream();
          br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream));
    } else {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(error));
    }
    String response = "";
    String nachricht;
    while ((nachricht = br.readLine()) != null){
          response += nachricht;
    }
    System.out.println(response);
    return con.getResponseCode();
}

private static int processDeleteRequest(URL url, String keyStore, String keyStorePassword) throws UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
    SSLSocketFactory sslFactory = getSSLSocketFactory(keyStore, keyStorePassword);
    HttpsURLConnection con = null;
    con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setSSLSocketFactory(sslFactory);
    con.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
    con.addRequestProperty("x-ms-version", "2013-08-01");
    return con.getResponseCode();
}

public static void getLocation(String keyStorePath, String keyStorePassword, String subscriptionId)
throws  UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException
{
    String url = "";
    // List locations
    url = String.format("https://management.core.windows.net/%s/locations", subscriptionId);
    String response = processGetRequest(new URL(url), keyStorePath, keyStorePassword);
    System.out.println(response);
}

public static void createCloudService(String keyStorePath, String keyStorePassword, String subscriptionId, String cloudService)
throws  UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException
{
    String url = "";
    // Create cloud service
    String label = "Cloud service in java";
    String description = "Cloud service in java";
    String location = "East US 2";
    url = String.format("https://management.core.windows.net/%s/services/hostedservices", subscriptionId);
    String requestBody = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><CreateHostedService xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure\"><ServiceName>%s</ServiceName><Label>%s</Label><Description>%s</Description><Location>%s</Location></CreateHostedService>";
    requestBody = String.format(requestBody, cloudService, Base64.encodeBase64String(label.getBytes()), description, location);
    int createResponseCode = processPostRequest(new URL(url), requestBody.getBytes(), "application/xml", keyStorePath, keyStorePassword);
    System.out.println("Created service: " + createResponseCode);
}

public static void deleteCloudService(String keyStorePath, String keyStorePassword, String subscriptionId, String cloudService)
throws  UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException
{
    String url = "";
    //Delete cloud service
    url = String.format("https://management.core.windows.net/%s/services/hostedservices/%s", subscriptionId, cloudService);
    int deleteResponseCode = processDeleteRequest(new URL(url), keyStorePath, keyStorePassword);
    System.out.println(deleteResponseCode);
}

public static void listImages(String keyStorePath, String keyStorePassword, String subscriptionId)
throws  UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException
{
    String url = "";
    String response = "";
    // List Images
    url = String.format("https://management.core.windows.net/%s/services/images", subscriptionId);
    response = processGetRequest(new URL(url), keyStorePath, keyStorePassword);
    System.out.println(response);
}

public static void listAutomationAccounts(String keyStorePath, String keyStorePassword, String subscriptionId)
throws  UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException
{
    String url = "";
    String response = "";
    // List automation accounts in a cloud service
    url = String.format("https://management.core.windows.net/%s/cloudServices/OaaSCSI6EGAZU6F6QTCK5XRVT45FKJC6RC7IQIQW3OPR7SVLE4ZPD4IQQQ-East-US?resourceType=AutomationAccount&detailLevel=Full&resourceProviderNamespace=automation", subscriptionId);
    response = processGetRequest(new URL(url), keyStorePath, keyStorePassword);
    System.out.println(response);
}

public static void checkCloudServiceAvailability(String keyStorePath, String keyStorePassword, String subscriptionId, String cloudService)
throws  UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException
{
    String url = "";
    String response = "";

    // Check service name availability
    url = String.format("https://management.core.windows.net/%s/services/hostedservices/operations/isavailable/%s", subscriptionId, cloudService);
    response = processGetRequest(new URL(url), keyStorePath, keyStorePassword);
    System.out.println(response);
}

public static void createAutomationAccount(String keyStorePath, String keyStorePassword, String subscriptionId)
throws  UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException
{
    String url = "";
    String response = "";
    // Create automation
    String automationName = "javaauto";
    String location = "East US 2";

    url = String.format("https://management.core.windows.net/%s/cloudServices/OaaSCSI6EGAZU6F6QTCK5XRVT45FKJC6RC7IQIQW3OPR7SVLE4ZPD4IQQQ-East-US/resources/automation/AutomationAccount/%s?resourceType=AutomationAccount&detailLevel=Full&resourceProviderNamespace=automation", subscriptionId, automationName);

    String requestBody = "<Response xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure\"><CloudServiceSettings><GeoRegion>East US 2</GeoRegion></CloudServiceSettings><SchemaVersion>1.0</SchemaVersion><Plan>Basic</Plan></Resource>";

    int createResponseCode = processPostRequest(new URL(url), requestBody.getBytes(), "application/xml", keyStorePath, keyStorePassword);

    System.out.println("CreateAutomationAccount " + createResponseCode);
}

// Create a published runbook
public static void createRunbook(String keyStorePath, String keyStorePassword, String subscriptionId)
throws  UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException
{
    String url = "";
    String response = "";
    // Create runbook 
    String runbookName = "Write-HellowWorld";
    String cloudService = <CLOUD_SERVICE>;

    url = String.format("https://management.core.windows.net/%s/cloudServices/%s/resources/automation/~/automationAccounts/javaauto/runbooks/%s?api-version=2014-12-08", subscriptionId, cloudService, runbookName);
    String requestBody = "{ \"tags\":{ \"Testing\":\"show value\", \"Source\":\"TechNet Script Center\" }, \"properties\":{ \"description\":\"Hello world\", \"runbookType\":\"Script\", \"logProgress\":false, \"publishContentLink\":{ \"uri\":\"https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/The-Hello-World-of-Windows-81b69574/file/111354/1/Write-HelloWorld.ps1\", \"contentVersion\":\"1.0.0.0\", \"contentHash\":{ \"algorithm\":\"sha256\", \"value\":\"EqdfsYoVzERQZ3l69N55y1RcYDwkib2+2X+aGUSdr4Q=\" } } } }";

    int createResponseCode = processPutRequest(new URL(url), requestBody.getBytes(), "application/json", keyStorePath, keyStorePassword);
    System.out.println("created runbook:: " + createResponseCode);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try {
        String subscriptionId = "<Insert your subscription ID>"; 
        String keyStorePath = "KeyStore.jks";
        String keyStorePassword = "secret321";

        String cloudService = "1testjava";

        //listImages(keyStorePath, keyStorePassword, subscriptionId);
        listAutomationAccounts(keyStorePath, keyStorePassword, subscriptionId);
        checkCloudServiceAvailability(keyStorePath, keyStorePassword, subscriptionId, cloudService);
        deleteCloudService(keyStorePath, keyStorePassword, subscriptionId, cloudService);
        createCloudService(keyStorePath, keyStorePassword, subscriptionId, cloudService);
        createAutomationAccount(keyStorePath, keyStorePassword, subscriptionId);

        // This also throws an error
        createRunbook(keyStorePath, keyStorePassword, subscriptionId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

For running this I've created a keystore file Keystore.jks and its .cer file using:

`keytool -genkeypair -alias keyfile -keyalg RSA -keystore KeyStore.jks 
-keysize 2048 -storepass "secret321"`

`keytool -v -export -file SMAPI.cer -keystore KeyStore.jks -alias keyfile`
`

The SMAPI.cer was uploaded to the Window Azure Portal, **Settings > Management Certificates**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code and found out two faults as follows.

1. Refer to the link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163820.aspx, the REST API for create an automation account is by using Http PUT method, not POST method.
   So I copied your function "processPostRequest" to new function "processPutRequest", and replaced "con.setRequestMethod("POST");" with "con.setRequestMethod("PUT");" and fixed it in the function "createAutomationAccount".
2. In your function "createAutomationAccount", the root mark name of request body xml is "Resource", not "Response".

It will work correctly until fix the faults.

Best Regards!

Comment: Can you help me to create a job as now that I've successfully created an automation a/c, inside it also created a runbook and published it. Now, I want to run the runbook. I am following this 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163849.aspx
there's no problem with the sending method 'PUT' now but it's giving an error "File or directory not found.&lt;/h2&gt;&#xD;  &lt;h3&gt;The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." 

I am not sure what'd be the jobID or from where I will get it.

Comment: Sure for your help request. However I suggest you to create a new thread for asking this question. It also can help anyone who has the same matter.

Comment: Please visit this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31940947/create-an-automation-job-to-execute-azure-runbook-using-rest-api