# Create an automation job to execute azure runbook using REST API

Tags: java, api, rest, azure, azure-automation

In this link ([Create azure automation account using REST api from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31858486/create-azure-automation-account-using-rest-api-from-java)) I'd asked about how to create an automation account in order to create runbook. Now, that I've created an automation account and also a runbook which is published, I want to execute(start) the runbook. In order to do so I am following this link (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163849.aspx) but I am getting an error:

```
Server Error&lt;/h1&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&#xD;&lt;div id="content"&gt;&#xD; &lt;div class="content-container"&gt;&lt;fieldset&gt;&#xD;  &lt;h2&gt;404 - File or directory not found.&lt;/h2&gt;&#xD;  &lt;h3&gt;The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable
```

This is the java function:

```
    private static int processPutRequest(URL url, byte[] data, String contentType, String keyStore, String keyStorePassword) 
    throws UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
       SSLSocketFactory sslFactory = getSSLSocketFactory(keyStore, keyStorePassword);
       HttpsURLConnection con = null;
       con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
       con.setSSLSocketFactory(sslFactory);
       con.setDoOutput(true);
       con.setRequestMethod("PUT");
       con.addRequestProperty("x-ms-version", "2013-08-01");
       con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(data.length));
       con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", contentType);

       DataOutputStream requestStream = new DataOutputStream (con.getOutputStream());
       requestStream.write(data);
       requestStream.flush();
       requestStream.close();

       System.out.println(con.getResponseMessage());

       InputStream error = ((HttpURLConnection) con).getErrorStream();

       BufferedReader br = null;
       if (error == null) {
          InputStream inputstream = con.getInputStream();
          br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream));
       } else {
          br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(error));
       }
       String response = "";
       String nachricht;
       while ((nachricht = br.readLine()) != null){
          response += nachricht;
       }
       System.out.println(response);
       return con.getResponseCode();
   }

   public static void createJobId(String keyStorePath, String keyStorePassword, String subscriptionId)
throws  UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException
   {
       String url = String.format("https://management.core.windows.net/%s/cloudServices/OaaSCSI6EGAZU6F6QTCK5XRVT45FKJC6RC7IQIQW3OPR7SVLE4ZPD4IQQQ-East-US/resources/automation/~/automationAccounts/xdtauto/jobs/8c3e715-9b27?api-version=2014-12-08", subscriptionId);
       String requestBody = "{ \"properties\":{ \"runbook\":{ \"name\":\"createVM\" } } }";
       int createResponseCode = processPutRequest(new URL(url), requestBody.getBytes(), "application/json", keyStorePath, keyStorePassword);
       System.out.println("JOB created :: " + createResponseCode);
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Joe's guess is correct.

Refer to the link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163849.aspx . As document shown,

> In Windows PowerShell, you can use the this command to create the job
>   ID:[GUID]::NewGuid().ToString().

The GUID in C#/.NET is generated by the functuion "System.Guid.NewGuid()". In Java, UUID is the same as GUID. Refer to the UUID Class link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html, it is generated by  the function  "java.util.UUID.randomUUID()".

So your code should be modified as following:

```
public static void createJobId(String keyStorePath, String keyStorePassword, String subscriptionId)
            throws UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            IOException {
        String automationName = <auto_account_name>;
        String jobId=java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        String url = String.format(
                "https://management.core.windows.net/%s/cloudServices/ OaaSCSI6EGAZU6F6QTCK5XRVT45FKJC6RC7IQIQW3OPR7SVLE4ZPD4IQQQ-East-US/resources/automation/~/automationAccounts/%s/jobs/%s?api-version=2014-12-08",
                subscriptionId, automationName, jobId);
        System.out.println("URL: "+url);
        String requestBody = "{ \"properties\":{ \"runbook\":{ \"name\":\"<RUNBOOK_NAME>\" } } }";
        int createResponseCode = processPutRequest(new URL(url), requestBody.getBytes(), "application/json",
                keyStorePath, keyStorePassword);
        System.out.println("JOB created :: " + createResponseCode);
    }
```

If you have created the runbook correctly and set up the correct runbook name in the request body, the code will run as expection and response the StatusCode 201.

However I found the other issue of the function "createRunbook" in your thread [Create azure automation account using REST api from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31858486/create-azure-automation-account-using-rest-api-from-java), the element " properties/publishContentLink/uri" is required in the request body of create runbook(refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163812.aspx).

[image]

So if the response body of create job include the information {"code":"NotFound","message":"Runbook not found."}, I suggest you to check your code and review the Runbook page on Azure Portal.

Comment: Yeah this is working like a charm. The runbook code I've updated. Much appreciated your help!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the error is due to the fact that you are not passing a proper GUID as the job id for the job to create. You are passing `8c3e715-9b27` but GUIDs are in the form `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure what to pass.
From where and how to get the GUID? As I've mentioned I am running a JAVA program..is there a way to get or create it programmatically from Java?